# Remove white space from string and compare option value to hide/show DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide/show DIV based on the option value of products.  Basically Shopify added option values automatically, including options that contains more than 1 word.  I don't have much control over that so I thought maybe I can remove the white space from the values and trigger the action.

```
<Select id="single-option-selector-product-template-0">
   <option value="Heather Ash">Heather Ash</option>
</Select>

<div id="HeatherAsh" class="colours" style="display:none">Heather Ash </div>
```

Here's the fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/clemckh/qtwuhb7r/14/

There was a similar question that was answered but this is different approach so I thought I should create a new thread. I am a JS beginner so my code is pretty messy.  Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to change the line which shows the div to `$('#' + optionValue).show();`: https://jsfiddle.net/2tcsd0xp (did you not see this message on chat?)

Comment: so, your last line should be `$('#' + optionValue).show();` , this will work

Comment: @Nick Sorry didn't notice your reply on chat.  Created this thread and thought would be nice to separate the two approaches.  The first answer you gave worked perfectly on one of my sites but didn't work on another so I think it must be something to do with the theme or some other scripts.  Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: @ClementCkh strange. This should be a bit more reliable - but it's definitely a pain that Shopify gives you these bad `id` values to begin with!

Comment: JUST REMOVE SPACE BETWEEN (Heather Ash) AND (Heather Grey )

Comment: I stated that Shopify adds option value automatically so I don't have much control over that.   Anyway the solution given above will provide some references for anyone who faces similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```js
jQuery(function() {
      jQuery('#single-option-selector-product-template-0').change(function() {
        $('.colours').hide();
        var optionValue = jQuery(this).val();
        optionValue = optionValue.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        $('#' + optionValue).show();
      });
    });
```

```html
<Select id="single-option-selector-product-template-0">
   <option value="White">White</option>
   <option value="Navy">Navy</option>
   <option value="Heather Ash">Heather Ash</option>
   <option value="Heather Grey">Heather Grey</option>
</Select>
<div id="White" class="colours" style="display:none"> White </div>
<div id="Navy" class="colours" style="display:none"> Navy </div>
<div id="HeatherAsh" class="colours" style="display:none">Heather Ash </div>
<div id="HeatherGrey" class="colours" style="display:none"> Heather Grey </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```